# Passing Variable to Curl Post Field

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, php-curl

I want to pass dynamic value stored in variable named as $order2, I want to pass that value to postfield using CURL Request.

```
<?php
 $order2 = "1604";
$curl2 = curl_init();



curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://ssapi.shipstation.com/orders/createlabelfororder",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>"{\n  \"orderId\": $order2 ,\n  \"carrierCode\": \"stamps_com\",\n  \"serviceCode\": \"usps_priority_mail\",\n  \"packageCode\": \"small_flat_rate_box\",\n  \"confirmation\": null,\n  \"shipDate\": \"2021-11-05\",\n  \"weight\": {\n    \"value\": 2,\n    \"units\": \"pounds\"\n  },\n  \"dimensions\": null,\n  \"insuranceOptions\": null,\n  \"internationalOptions\": null,\n  \"advancedOptions\": null,\n  \"testLabel\": true\n}",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Host: ssapi.shipstation.com",
    "Authorization:Basic MYAUTHCODE",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
  ),
));

$response2 = curl_exec($curl2);

curl_close($curl2);
echo $response2;
```

It is returning me following response :

> {"Message":"The request is
> invalid.","ModelState":{"request.orderId":["Error reading integer.
> Unexpected token: Undefined. Path 'orderId', line 2, position 15."]}}

Comment: Please do not build your own json. Create an array, then use [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: _"Unexpected token: Undefined"_ seems to suggest that `$order2` isn't defined at the point where it's being used.

Comment: If I'm counting the characters correctly, it's balking at the space between `$order2 ,`. Another reason to not build your own json.

Comment: As @aynber suggested that is the best way, but you forgot the double quotes `\"orderId\": \"$order2\" ,\n`